# Configuring Websocket, Nodejs, Webpack on a Vagrant Ubuntu machine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, websocket, vagrant, webpack-dev-server

**The Problem**

I have been struggling the past few days trying to get my `react hot loader` to work on my Vagrant machine running Ubuntu - `14.04`.  However, whenever I configure `webpack-dev-server` to run on the same `host:port` (`'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:80/',`) as my vagrant machine, I am continually met the following errors:

[image: error output]

**The Configurations - webpack-config.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:80/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    watchOptions: {
  poll: true
},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'app/index.tpl.html',
          inject: 'body',
          filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    eslint: {
        configFile: '.eslintrc',
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: false
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json?$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file' }
        ]
    }
};
```

**server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // It suppress error shown in console, so it has to be set to false.
    quiet: false,
    // It suppress everything except error, so it has to be set to false as well
    // to see success build.
    noInfo: false,
    stats: {
      // Config for minimal console.log mess.
      assets: false,
      colors: true,
      version: false,
      hash: false,
      timings: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }
}).listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

  console.log('Listening at localhost:8080');
});
```

**Conclusion**

I have a reverse proxy that will port `8080` to `80` which my server is currently running on.  If I try running the `webpack-dev-server` in port `8080` I get a connection refused, which that does not make sense, but with port `80` it seems to work fine.

My initial instinct is telling me this is probably an `apache2` configuration issue since I have tried using many different boilerplate projects that are suppose to `work` out of the box to validate the concern, it is indeed a configuration issue on my part.

If you have any suggestions or are familiar with this type of setup, please share.

Merry Chisrtmas